Linux Systemd Socket does not work
i've got the Systemd error Message:
Sep 20 15:54:29 test  systemd[9298]: HostnameResponder.socket: Failed to create listening socket (0.0.0.0:101): Permission denied
Sep 20 15:54:29 test  systemd[1]: HostnameResponder.socket: Failed to receive listening socket (0.0.0.0:101): Input/output error
Sep 20 15:54:29 test  systemd[1]: HostnameResponder.socket: Failed to listen on sockets: Input/output error
Sep 20 15:54:29 test  systemd[1]: HostnameResponder.socket: Failed with result 'resources'.

My systemd Files
HostnameResponder.socket
[Unit]
Description=HostnameResponder

[Socket]
ListenStream=0.0.0.0:101
Accept=yes
#NoDelay=true
#FreeBind=true

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target

HostnameResponder@.service
[Unit]
Description=HostnameResponder Per-Connection Server

[Service]
ExecStart=-/usr/bin/hostname -A
#User=nobody
#Group=nobody
StandardInput=socket
PrivateUsers=true
ProtectHome=true
DynamicUser=yes
StandardOutput=socket

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

I don't understand whats going wrong ...

Well, it's a permission error & it points to an ordinary user trying to open a port < 1024. Only root can do that. Try port 1101.

....and if you are already root, then check that something else isn't already using the address+port

If i using "/usr/bin/cat /etc/hostname" .. that works .. it look liks it is a Problem with "/usr/bin/hostname"
